# jQuery click event prepending paragraph tag twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a click event that is prepending a paragraph tag to an element twice and I'm not understanding why.  Can anyone give me a reason?
**jQuery**

```
function select_menu(){
    var select = $(".select");
    var option_menu = $(".option-menu");
    var option = $(".option");
    select.on("click", function(){
        $(this).find(option_menu).toggle();
        select = $(this);
        $(this).find(option_menu).each(function(){
            $(".current").hide();
            if($(this).hasClass("current")){
                $(this).removeClass("current");
            }
            else{
                $(this).show().addClass("current");
            }
        })
    })

    option.on("click", function(){
        select.children("p").remove();
        var value = $(this).text();
        select.prepend("<p><input type='hidden' name='center' id='center' value='" +value +"' />" +value +"<p>");
    })

    $(document).on("click", function(ev){
        if($(ev.target).closest(".select").length === 0){
            $(".current").hide().removeClass("current");
        }
    })
}
```

Here's the area where the script prepends the paragraph tag to.
**HTML**

```
<fieldset for="center">
    <label>Center:</label>
    <div class="select" name="center_menu" id="center_menu">
        <div class="arrow"></div>
        <div class="option-menu">
            <?php
                $query = "SELECT * FROM $centers";
                $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
                global $center_name;
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                    $center_name = "{$row['center']}";
                    echo "<div class='option'>" .$center_name ."</div>";
                }
           ?>
       </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Can you also post HTML?

Comment: Sure thing, it's posted

Comment: Is it just the paragraph tag or also the input field that get's prepended twice? Note: your missing a closing tag on your `<p>`

Comment: Thanks Tim, that's exactly what the problem was

Answer (score 1):

In your code:

```
select.prepend("<p><input type='hidden' name='center' id='center' value='" +value +"' />" +value +"<p>");
```

you open and close the paragraph tag the same way. There should be a closing tag.

The page recognizes it like two separate paragraph tags and closes them automatically. Probably this will fix your issue.